How can I mock doucment.location.href in Angular unit test
I am struggling with mocking the absolute path in Angular.
  it('should return current URL when no URL provided and og:url meta tag does not exist', () => {
    const currentUrl: string = 'https://example.com/current';

    const documentSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('document', ['location']);
    documentSpy.location.and.returnValue({ href: currentUrl });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ShareService,
        { provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: documentSpy }
      ]
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(ShareService);

    expect((service as any).getComputedUrl('')).toEqual(currentUrl);
  });

The problem with this code it replaces the document object, removing functions like querySelector which causes the test to fail
Is there an angular service that return the absolute path that I can use to mock?

I think you should use spyOnProperty. https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOnProperty
I believe that you have injected DOCUMENT in your service.
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

In test:
it(...) {
  documentSpy = TestBed.inject(DOCUMENT)
  spyOnProperty(documentSpy, 'location', 'get').and.returnValue({ href: currentUrl })
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ShareService,
      { provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: documentSpy }
    ]
  });
  ...
}

